# Using scikit Learn - Neural network to produce ROC Curves

Tags: python, neural-network, scikit-learn, statistics, confusion-matrix

I want to verify that the logic of the way I am producing ROC curves is correct. (irrelevant of the technical understanding of the actual code). I have a data set which I want to classify. I am using a neural network specifically `MLPClassifier` function form python's `scikit Learn` module.

I am passing a training data set to the `fit` function and then using the `predict` function with the testing data set. I am then outputting a confusion matrix with a false positive value and a true positive value.

what I would like to do is calculate a ROC curve where I need a set of true positive and false positive values. would it make sense to run the neural network (`MLPClassifier`) multiple times with different targets each time and record the different true positive and false positive values?

It seems simple enough for me. Is it the right way to produce a ROC curve with a neural network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [sklearn.metrics.roc_curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html).

Besides, [Here](https://github.com/1996scarlet/Python-VScode/blob/fd9cc5c80342ead436b1dfc55e48f4200bc70ccb/OLD/work3-2.py) is an example of what you want to do.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
fpr2, tpr2, threshold = roc_curve(y_test, clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
```